# Can I move the Google Copyright on overlayed google map bottom of my site?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was draw a map for Google Maps. I'm using it overlayed on Google Map API v3.

If I move the Google Logo and Terms Of Use link to bottom of page on my site, Will I use the Google Map API v3 like as shown on attached image?

I read the Terms of use of Google Map but I couldnt find any copyright information about overlayed map api.

My Overlayed Google IMAGE : http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/5595/overlayedgooglemap.png

Comment: I don't think that's allowed, they won't find out verry fast but still. Why would you do this anyway.

Comment: No, you can't. It is prohibited by Terms of Use of Google Maps API.

Comment: It can be by css but like @wf9a5m75 said that is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Terms of Use of Google Maps API, section 9.4, 10.1.1.(f)

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms