# Move google maps logo above custom interface on bottom. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display some semi-transparent interface on bottom of google maps, therefore I need to move google logo without breaking terms of service. In google android docs I saw `setPadding()` just for this purpose, but I can't find anything similar for web javascript google maps API.
So how can I achieve that?

***Not a duplicate:*** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419027/can-i-move-the-google-copyright-on-overlayed-google-map-bottom-of-my-site) is about moving logo out of map's scope. For moving it inside map there is already some means in Android API, so i want to know what is the way to do this in JS. If there is one.

***Update:*** Ok it seems that I was somehow not clear enough. In android API there is an **official** means to change placement of logo. Refer to this [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=mdr-gdl#map_padding)

**As per the Google Maps API terms of service, your application must not remove or obscure the Google logo or copyright notices. Map padding allows you to reposition these elements if necessary. If you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be visible.**

Please do not emphasise that I can't move logo in ANY way. It's a false assumption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I move the Google Copyright on overlayed google map bottom of my site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419027/can-i-move-the-google-copyright-on-overlayed-google-map-bottom-of-my-site)

Comment: So where is it answered? Im not trying to replace or move logo out of map's scope, on android there is means to set map paddings that will move logo, i want to know what is the way to do this in JS

Comment: @Rhono forgot to link you.

Comment: It's answered on that page, just not accepted. See [the terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#9-license-requirements), section 9.4, A: "Content provided to you through the Service may contain the Brand Features of Google ... . When Google provides those Brand Features or other attribution through the Service, **you must display such attribution as provided** ... and must not delete or alter the attribution." Emphasis mine.

Comment: @Rhono only partially true, as i already mentioned official android API, check my update, links and direct quote from google api.

Comment: It is really frusterating that the community is *not reading* the question before answering. Google documents their official method for making sure the logo/attribution is visible but it is Android only. They will not document how to comply with the terms in JavaScript. Please how do you display their official logo/attributions on a page that has a fixed footer?! The map's padding must be adjusted and yet the JS API has no `setPadding` method like the Android API has. People (like myself) are _trying_ to do the right thing and *not* cover it up.

Comment: It would seem Google has left JS developers out to dry: https://issuetracker.google.com/35820483

Answer (score 3):

From [Can I overlay Google Logo on map or move it to top right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968399/can-i-overlay-google-logo-on-map-or-move-it-to-top-right)
user Tuxzone answer helps me.

```
      var css = document.createElement("style");
      css.type = "text/css";
      css.innerHTML = "#map"+" div div a[target='_blank'] div{marginbottom:50px;} ";
      document.head.appendChild(css);  
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

[image]

Comment: What will this do? As far as i remember google maps and logo were in iframe and unreachable by the outside css, can't see how creating styles through js will help that.
This question is pretty old anyway and i'm not working with google maps currently, so if someone will confirm that this works and/or post a screenshot - i'll accept it.